# Why is CO2 not in the C∞v point group?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, symmetry

It seems to me that CO2, since it can be linearly rotated around the z-axis without change of shape, ought to be in the C∞v point group.  However, in all the character tables I can find, it's listed as a D∞h.  What's the difference between these two, and why does CO2 fall in the D∞h and not the C∞v?

Comment: In short, the two O atoms are equivalent, but $C_{\infty h}$ fails to acknowledge this, so you add more symmetry elements that switch these two atoms, and so you end up with $D_{\infty h}$ .

Comment: Okay, I *almost* got that.  What symmetry operations would switch the O's which wouldn't apply to a C∞v (assuming that's what you meant?) group?

Comment: Why, many. Think of all these perpendicular $C_2$ axes, to begin with.

Comment: Oh, of course.  Duh, my stupid.  Sorry, and thanks!  If you have time to post a complete answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Crazy how it is; now it's clicked I can't believe I didn't get it before.  :)

Comment: For concrete examples, consider the two linear species: $\ce{OCO}$ versus $\ce{OCN-}$.

Comment: Gotcha.  So linear H3+ would be $D∞h$, since there is a horizontal plane of symmetry through the centre of the middle hydrogen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are linear with a $C_{\infty}$ axis, but $D_{\infty h}$ has a center of inversion and $C_{\infty v}$ does not.

Comment: And that all-important $sigma_h$ mirror plane perpendicular to the rotation axis, giving the name of the point group.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison - Yes but for a linear molecule you don't need to identify a center of inversion, $i$, and a mirror plane perpendicular to the rotation axis ($\sigma_h$). For a linear molecule, if the center of inversion exists so must the perpendicular  mirror plane, and if the perpendicular  mirror plane exists so must the center of inversion.

Comment: Of course - I just wanted to point out the mirror plane because it’s in the name of the point group. Exactly as you say, you can deduce one by the other.

Answer (score 4):

It will be easier to understand by giving an example of molecules:
$D_{\infty h} \to \ce{CO_2}$,
$C_{\infty v} \to \ce{HCN}$.

Both are linear molecules, however $\ce{CO_2}$ has an inversion, $\ce{HCN}$ does not.