# Why must polar molecules be asymetrical?

Tags: electronegativity, polarity, dipole

As I understand, polarity in molecules comes from the difference in electronegativity or the ability of the atoms to attract eletrons so the electrons spend more time or are more probable to gravitate more around the atom with stronger electronegativity right? So I wonder why polar molecules must necessarily have an asymetrical structure? (as I've read on multiple sites). Shouldn't a symetrical atom with strong electronegativity with 2 atoms bonded linearly 180° on both sides which are significantly less electronegative, be polar since the electrons would gravitate more towards the center and the sides would then be more positively charged? What am I missing here?

[image: Drawing of my question]

Why is the first molecule (1) not possible? Is it becuase of the less polar atom on the left side repells electrons just as much as the one on the right? But then the electrons would still orbit the middle atom more because its more elctronegative, right?

Comment: I meant gravitate not orbit in the last sentence

Comment: You ain't missing anything. The first molecule is surely possible, and indeed does exist (think CO2), and is quite definitely very polar. Some people would claim it isn't polar because it has zero dipole moment. They are irrelevant.

Comment: So symetrical molecules can be polar and the sources that say otherwise are wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Or https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14641/why-is-carbon-dioxide-nonpolar

Comment: Zero net dipole moment means zero net dipole, just that. Molecules shouldn't be call polar, it only leads to misunderstandings. *Solvents* can and should be, but still with some measure of caution.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I have a feeling OP might just not get how dipoles work.

Comment: @IvanNeretin and @ Mithoron, I think you are touching on something important.  Most courses that introduce the concept of polarity/dipoles in the context of molecular structure use vectors to describe the dipoles of the individual bonds, and then the sum of those vectors to determine the dipole moment (at least qualitatively) of the molecule.  In that case, a molecule like CO2 would be non-polar.  Perhaps you should elaborate for the OP and other readers.

Comment: @MichaelLautman We did, on a number of occasions.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, I only saw the link that was posted after my comment.  I can retract my comment if you like.

Comment: Thank you for answers and for this link whoever posted it https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_Chemistry_(Zumdahl_and_Decoste)/08%3A_Bonding_General_Concepts/13.03_Bond_Polarity_and_Dipole_Moments  I thought the dipole came from the individual parts of the molecule now I understand that its the whole molecule's +/- that is Directionaly not negated or that the symetrical polar parts of the atom cancel eachother out directionaly so the molecule doesn't seek equilibrium in others because it alredy has it

Comment: @MichaelLautman No, leave it, because it is still useful.

Comment: Zan what you say is certainly true as far you look at parts of the molecule. Those are polar bonds. The various electrical moments can sum up to cancel each other and this requires a symmetrical arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_polarity) definition of *chemical polarity*, which is standard (if not [IUPAC](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/P/P04710.html)) usage:

> In chemistry, polarity is a separation of electric charge leading to a molecule or its chemical groups having an electric dipole moment, with a negatively charged end and a positively charged end.

then it's not hard to understand why a molecule such as $\ce{CO2}$ containing a [center of inversion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/103950/why-is-co2-not-in-the-c%E2%88%9Ev-point-group) lacks a [dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#Molecular_dipoles) and is therefore "nonpolar", as are, by this definition, other molecules with [high symmetry](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Symmetry_(Vallance)/04._Symmetry_and_physical_properties) properties and lacking a net dipole moment:

> The only groups compatible with a dipole moment are Cn, Cnv and Cs. In molecules belonging to Cn or Cnv the dipole must lie along the axis of rotation.

Comment: It's not " bound to be canonical". IUPAC def. only applies polarity to solvents,  which this article is missing almost entirely.

Comment: @Mithoron I used "canonical" to mean "standard" in this case, but you have a  point, I was a bit loose with language.